# I have a code where a lateinit variable was initialized after it was called and I don't know how

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

While I was following up with the Developing Android Apps with Kotlin course on udacity I found that the instructor has made a lateinit variable `lateinit var diceImage: ImageView` as she will initialize it later before it's called 
***The lateinit variable was called in the rollDice()** function but the variable was initialized after the function was called in the setOnClickListner

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollDice()
        }
        diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_Image)
```

You can find the full code below

```
 package com.example.diceroller

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var rollNumber:Int = 0
    lateinit var diceImage: ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_Button)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollDice()
        }
        diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_Image)
    }
    fun rollDice() {
        val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.dice_Image)
        var randomInt: Int
        do {
           randomInt = Random.nextInt(6) + 1
        } while (randomInt == rollNumber)
        rollNumber = randomInt
        when (rollNumber) {
            1 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
            2 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
            3 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_3)
            4 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_4)
            5 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_5)
            else -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_6)
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am new to android development I don't How did she initialize it after calling it in the roleDice() function

Can anyone clear this out for me? .... Shouldn't it be called before the setOnClickListner?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setOnClickListener` just registers a callback lambda that will be invoked whenever the `rollButton` is clicked, calling `setOnClickListener` does not immediately invoke `rollDice()`. The `onCreate()` method gets called very early in the `AppCompatActivity`'s lifecycle, so your users won't be able to tap the button before the `diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_Image)` line runs, hence this is code is perfectly safe.

Comment: as I understood from your answer that when the onCreate method get called it invokes all the commands inside it ignoring the setOnclickListner at first....did i get it right ?

Comment: `onCreate` *will* call `rollButton.setOnClickListener`, however, it will not call the `{ rollDice() }` lambda that you pass to `setOnClickListener` - that lambda will only be executed once the user taps the `rollButton`.

Comment: also notice that in the rollDice() there is a new val created for `diceImage`, so it's not even using the lateinit var

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Fragent of code below doesn't actually run the `rollDice` method. It only sets the listener so that program knows that when the `rollButton` is clicked, `rollDice` method should be called.

```
rollButton.setOnClickListener {
    rollDice()
}
```

You can see that all this is in `onCreate` function, so it's like the user will only be able to do anything, like click a button, only after the activity will be fully initialized, so after the `onCreate` is finished.

Comment: Thanks for your help!